# Expand menu, show submenu

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to create an "expandable" menu. So, if a user clicks on option A two suboptions should show up. I'm trying to do something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/68RXP/211/) but in a menu...

This is my code so far...

```
<li>
 <a href="?op=1" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse88"><i class="icon-picture icon-white"></i> Galleries</a>
                        <div class="nav-collapse88">
                            <ul>
                                  <li>
                                    <a href=""><i class="icon-play"></i> Add</a>
                                  </li>
                                  <li>
                                    <a href=""><i class="icon-play"></i> Delete</a>
                                  </li>
                             </ul>
                        </div>
                      </li>
```

So when I click on galleries the options Add and Delete should appear. Any suggestions?

Comment: [Bootstrap Dropdown Reference](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#dropdowns)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would nest ul's like so:

```
<ul>
   <li>
      <a class="expand">Link used to expand</a>
      <ul>
        <li>Sub Menu Item</li>
        <li>Sub Menu Item</li>
        <li>Sub Menu Item</li>
      </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

The I would use this jquery:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a.expand', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).siblings('ul').slideToggle();
});
```

You would need to set the sub menu CSS to display none.

Something along these lines should do the trick.

Comment: Are you sure it will work? I think $(this) is anchor element and querying dom for UL wont return anything. Instead you should use siblings("ul") I suppose

Comment: Yes sorry, use siblings not find.

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
<ul>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="?op=1">Support</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
      <li><a href=""><i class="icon-play"></i> Add</a></li>
      <li><a href=""><i class="icon-play"></i> Delete</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: It's not enough, he should also add dropdown.js

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want the class to be dropdown not collapse.  That's how the bootstrap documentation recommends it for menus.

Change the class to be `dropdown`, remove the inner div, and add the class `dropdown-menu` the inner ul.

```
<li class="dropdown">
<a href="?op=1" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="icon-picture icon-white"></i>>Galleries</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                              <li>
                                <a href=""><i class="icon-play"></i> Add</a>
                              </li>
                              <li>
                                <a href=""><i class="icon-play"></i> Delete</a>
                              </li>
                         </ul>
                  </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

tyy this http://jsfiddle.net/68RXP/213/

```
$(function(){
        $(".nav-collapse88").hide();
        $("a").click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $(".nav-collapse88", $(this).parent()).slideToggle();        
        });
    })​
<li>
 <a href="?op=1">
     <i class="icon-picture icon-white"></i> Galleries</a>
                        <div class="nav-collapse88">
                            <ul>
                                  <li>
                                    <a href=""><i class="icon-play"></i> Add</a>
                                  </li>
                                  <li>
                                    <a href=""><i class="icon-play"></i> Delete</a>
                                  </li>
                             </ul>
                        </div>
                      </li>​
```