# Very simple jquery causes error

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Related to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13880519/expand-menu-show-submenu) I am getting this error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

with this code:

```
<!-- Le javascript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script src="js/inspiritas.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap-dropdown.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap-collapse.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(document).on('click', 'a.expand', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).find('ul').slideToggle();
        });
    });​
    </script>
```

The error is in the last });
I don't see anything wrong, removing the js files doesnt help.

Comment: That block doesn't have any syntax error. I suspect the error is in one of your referenced `<script>` files. Also, you have a `ul` within an `a`?

Comment: I'm not sure if it will help, but you could try adding `type="text/javascript"` to your script block declaration.

Comment: you don't need `$(document).ready(function() {` around the `$(document).on` to attach the event handler correctly

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Last line of code, you have an illegal invisible character.

```
    });​  // <--- right here
```

This happens when you copy/paste from jsFiddle or perhaps other sites.

Delete that line, and some of the space around it, and retype it manually.

Comment: You do your name honour. You're too damn fast.
Also: Some text editors will display the hidden character, Notepad++ for example, will display a `?`.